# Как ПРАВИЛЬНО сделать ссылку <a> без перехода на другую страницу, но при этом и без изменения URL?

Tags: html, href

Есть тег anchor на html странице. По нажатию на него открывается модальное окошко. Естественно в событии `onclick` пишем `return false`, но нужно указать что-то в `href`, чтобы ссылка была кликабельна. Если указать например `#777` в `href`, то по нажатию на ссылку `#777` добавится к текущему URL, что не очень красиво.

Как правильно оформить `href`, чтобы не добавлялось в URL ничего. Вариант `javascript:void(0)`, не предлагать, потому что глючный. Ситуация именно такая, какая есть, без исключений - без перехода и чтобы не было лишнего в URL

Comment: Если указан `return false;`, то к адресу ничего добавляться не должно. И в чём глючность варианта с `javascript:void(0);`?

Comment: Еще можно `event.preventDefault()` использовать

Comment: И еще можно не ссылки юзать, а любой другой объект с css `cursor: pointer;`

Comment: @korytoff, поддерживаю. Ссылки лучше использовать тогда, когда в `href` можно прописать то, что обеспечит нормальную работу страницы для пользователей с отключенным JavaScript.

Comment: @korytoff, нельзя. С клавиатуры тогда навигация на неё работать не будет. И на ссылку без href - тоже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае использовать не тег `<a>`, а любой другой с css: `cursor: pointer;`.

А если уж так нужно через `<a>` и js то можно добавлять событие современным способом:

```
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}, false);
```

PS. Код не тестировал, может немного не точно, привык блин к `jQuery`;

Answer (score 1):

`href="#"` - чтобы у ссылки был непустой href и на неё можно было перейти используя <kbd>tab</kbd>.

`event.preventDefault()` в обработчике, чтобы не менялся адрес.